# Showing the user that he has logged out

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, logout

I want this: If the user logs out(session destroy) then index should say: You are logged out.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] == true) {
echo "Welcome on the users page!, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
    } 
    elseif (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    echo "You logged out..";}
```

The problem I am having is that it also shows you logged out when you haven't even logged in to be able to log out. I only want it to show if the user logs out.

Also I only want "You are logged out" to show up once. If you refresh the page, it should be gone

Comment: If you wish a quick fix, you should set your $_SESSION['user'] as false by default then unsetting it when your user is logging out. But it's not really clean... Or maybe defining an other session variable for just poping your error message only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using php unset(); function to destroy a session, you can actually save boolean "false" in the $_SESSION["user"];

For example, in you logout page:

Instead of destroying, set session to false

Ex:

``
    //When logging out
    $_SESSION["user"] = false;

```
//now to check if user logged out

if($_SESSION["user"] === false) {

echo "you logged out";

}elseif(!isset($_SESSION["user"])) {//when the session finally expires
echo " you haven't logged in";

}else{
echo "you are logged in";
}


 //to get rid of it after page reload,    you need to unset the SESSION


unset($_SESSION["user"]);
```

Comment: Works now, only need to find out how to get rid of it when refreshing it. Thanks.

Comment: You can get rid of it by actually destroying the $_SESSION['user']; check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the following condition:

```
!isset($_SESSION['user']
```

This is true whether the user logged-in or not. So you have to make some other session variable to check for the user logged out. And that is only set when the user logged out.

Ex:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['user'] && isset($_SESSION['logged_out']))
{
    // isset($_SESSION['user'] to check if user logged out and extra condition to check if user comes here after logged-out.
}
```

and check this on index page.

Comment: I know why my code is wrong, but how to check if the user logged out?